# Is there any framework available to provide Microsoft Onenote Web like UX interms of rich text editor?

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor

In OneNote there is a free white page, while you are adding something to page you don't deal with positioning. 
Wherever your cursor is once you start writing something that thing will appear there. You don't have to align it again.
But most of rich text editor out there is working similar to Microsoft Word or equivalent tools.

Is there any existing free/non-free Javascript library for **rich text editor** that provides similar experience like Microsoft One note.